# When calling a ViewModel in a Controller, repeatedly, does the ViewModel's constructor wipe out other values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

<sub>I've tried searching for an answer to this question, but I'm only getting responses like passing data to a Controller, which isn't what I'm asking about. If there is an answer to my question here on SO, please let me know.</sub>

- We have a ViewModel that has another class instance (`InventoryIn`) as a property of the ViewModel class.
- It's our intent to class the same view repeatedly, passing the ViewModel back to the same view. We populate the `InventoryIn` data in the view, but when it gets called a second time, the InventoryIn instance is empty.
- The only explanation I can come up for this behavior is the `InventoryIn` constructor, where we do instantiate some properties. So, my question is when passing a ViewModel repeatedly to the same view, in a Controller, does the ViewModel's constructor always get invoked? We thought that wouldn't happen, but we might be wrong.

BTW, the structure of the view is it has two `<form>` tags. One with a button that posts to the same view, and the constructor is invoked with the same action method that was used when the view was first called. Then the second `<form>` tag has an action method that posts to a different view that's called from the same controller.

Addendum - Action Methods from the Controller

```
        public IActionResult Step1()
        {
            var newSiteToSite = new SiteToSite();
            //do stuff here with newSiteToSite
            return View(newSiteToSite);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Step2(SiteToSite SiteToSite)
        {
            // THIS COULD BE COMING FROM STEP 1 OR STEP 2
            if (Step1IsValid(SiteToSite))
            {
                RefreshSiteToSite(SiteToSite);
                // RETURN STEP 2 VIEW
                return View("Step2", SiteToSite);
            // STEP 1 IS INVALID
            } else {
                // RETURN STEP 1 VIEW
                return View("Step1", SiteToSite);
            }
        }
```

The code for RefreshSiteToSite:

```
private void RefreshSiteToSite(SiteToSite siteToSite)
{
    SetOriginatingLocation(siteToSite);

    SetDestinationLocation(siteToSite);

    int invOutItemPackageReceiptId = siteToSite.InvOutItemPackageReceiptID;
    GetSiteToSiteById(siteToSite, invOutItemPackageReceiptId);
}
```

code from SetOriginatingLocation():

```
private void SetOriginatingLocation(SiteToSite siteToSite)
{
    var originatingLocation = db.PharmLocations.Where(p => p.LocationId == siteToSite.OriginatingLocationID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (originatingLocation != null)
    {
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationCode = originatingLocation.LocationCode;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationName = originatingLocation.Location;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationAddress1 = originatingLocation.Address1;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationAddress2 = originatingLocation.Address2;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationLocCity = originatingLocation.LocCity;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationLocState = originatingLocation.LocState;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationLocZip = originatingLocation.LocZip;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationPhoneMain = originatingLocation.PhoneMain;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationPhoneAlt = originatingLocation.PhoneAlt;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationFax = originatingLocation?.Fax;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationContact1Name = originatingLocation?.Contact1Name;
        siteToSite.OriginatingLocationContact2Name = originatingLocation?.Contact2Name;
    }
}
```

SetDestinationLocation code:

```
private void SetDestinationLocation(SiteToSite siteToSite)
{
    var destinationLocation = db.PharmLocations.Where(p => p.LocationId == siteToSite.DestinationLocationID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (destinationLocation != null)
    {
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationCode = destinationLocation.LocationCode;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationName = destinationLocation.Location;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationAddress1 = destinationLocation.Address1;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationAddress2 = destinationLocation.Address2;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationLocCity = destinationLocation.LocCity;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationLocState = destinationLocation.LocState;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationLocZip = destinationLocation.LocZip;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationPhoneMain = destinationLocation.PhoneMain;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationPhoneAlt = destinationLocation.PhoneAlt;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationFax = destinationLocation?.Fax;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationContact1Name = destinationLocation?.Contact1Name;
        siteToSite.DestinationLocationContact2Name = destinationLocation?.Contact2Name;
    }
}
```

GetSiteToSiteByID code:

```
private void GetSiteToSiteById(SiteToSite siteToSite, int id)
{
    var tmp = db.VwPart1SiteToSites.Where(p => p.InvOutItemPackageReceiptId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        if (siteToSite.CurrentVwPart1s == null)
        {
            siteToSite.CurrentVwPart1s = new List<VwPart1SiteToSite>();
        }
        siteToSite.CurrentVwPart1s.Add(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Controller's entire action method (signature and body), especially the part where you call `.View(...)`, _and_ please post all the relevant parts of all Views (`.cshtml` and/or non-WebForms `.aspx`), especially the `@model` line.

Comment: answer is yes. So you need to pass the model back to the view model on post.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong we are sending the same view model back when posting to itself again.

Comment: @Dai I'll amend the question with the relevant Controller code

Comment: You need to put everything into a ViewModel including the void. Then u call the action base on the needed action. Are you using MVC5 or core? Do you use DI?